# Is using yoda conditions with c# justified?

Tags: c#, coding-style, readability

It's mind bending experiencing reading code like :

```
"Aggregation".Equals(evt.Id))
```

I was unsuccessful in trying to talk the person out of this style, maybe I'm wrong? 
Or maybe I wasn't articulate enough, hence the post here.

Comment: Could `evt.Id` be `null`? Perhaps. You do not want to call methods on `null`. `"Aggregation"` is not `null`, for sure. Although, why not `==`? Yeah, use `==` instead. If you had a reason not to, you probably should be using an equality comparer.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not justified.

It makes some sense to do this for string comparisons in Java where calling `.equals` on a string variable can result in a NullPointerException, so:

```
myString.equals("foo")
```

Can be made safer by doing:

```
"foo".equals(myString)
```

This is not really relevant in C# which uses the `==` operator for string comparisons. This is safe to use with null references. The same is true of `String.Equals`.

Comment: In languages that use `==` for comparisons, Yoda conditions are often used to prevent accidental assignments in conditions (`if (myValue = "foo") then ...`). Some languages disallow assignments in condition blocks for this reason. I believe C# is among those? Which would indeed mean it's a lot harder to justify.

Comment: @Duroth In C# a statement like `if (myValue = "foo") { ... }` yields a compilation error saying that 'string' cannot be implicitly converted to 'bool'. Even when using `if (myBoolValue = true) { ... }`, the compiler issues a warning saying that the expression is constant and thr author probably meant to use == instead of =. So yeah, in C# there is usually no need for yoda conditions.

Comment: @Duroth making sure your code actually works is what tests are for.